# List of WordPress menu item indices?

Tags: menus, admin, dashboard

The following code will rename the "Posts" menu item to "Blog Posts" in the WordPress Dashboard:

```
function lc_change_post_menu_label() {
global $menu;
$menu[5][0] = 'Blog Posts';

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'lc_change_post_menu_label' );
```

Works fine, and all is well. Problem is, I want to target other menu items, for example I want to rename "Pages" to "Site Pages". Is there a list somewhere that contains the index number for all WP admin menu items? `var_dump` isn't helping and I don't have a lot of time to waste since I've already wasted almost two hours of trial and error, trying to target these silly things.

Answer (score 0):

So after a whole bunch of digging I found what I was looking for near the bottom of this page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page#Examples